# Neo4j - Invalid Query error occured

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have tried following query in cypher.

```
START other=node(*)
WHERE other.FirstName =~ "(?i)dh.*" AND other.UserID <> 1 
WITH other, me=node:node_auto_index(UserID = '1')
MATCH me-[myR:friends]-(x)
RETURN other.UserID, other.UserName, other.FirstName, other.LastName, other.ImagePath 
       // myR.ApprovalStatus, COUNT(distinct pMutualFriends) AS mutualFriends
//ORDER BY mutualFriends DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

but it is giving me error.

```
These columns can't be listen in the WITH statement without renaming: me=node
```

so, What is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do another START clause to do this:

```
START other=node(*)
WHERE other.FirstName =~ "(?i)dh.*" AND other.UserID <> 1 
WITH other
START me=node:node_auto_index(UserID = '1')
MATCH me-[myR:friends]-(x)
RETURN other.UserID, other.UserName, other.FirstName, other.LastName, other.ImagePath 
   // myR.ApprovalStatus, COUNT(distinct pMutualFriends) AS mutualFriends
//ORDER BY mutualFriends DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

That should be syntactically correct. I'm not exactly sure what your query is trying to do--it doesn't feel right, because the two queries are not linked together with a `match`, so you're going to get the cartesian product of `other` and `me`/`x` in the results.

Comment: thanks @wes-freeman, please have a look at my another question. link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917884/join-result-set/17933098?noredirect=1#17933098