# Join result set

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I want mutual count of my friends with friendship status. I have created nodes for each user and created relationship with properties between them. I have found my desired result as per following queries. In this test case my login userid=1, and I want to search those users which is started from letter 'dh'. so, my query is as follows.

```
1st Query : which is returned all users with specific given keyword.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
START other=node(*)
WHERE other.FirstName =~ "(?i)dh.*" AND other.UserID <> 1 
WITH other, me=node:node_auto_index(UserID = '1')
RETURN other.UserID, other.UserName, other.FirstName, other.LastName, other.ImagePath 
LIMIT 100;
```

This query returns me all users started with 'dh'
Now, I want friendship status between my login user and this searched users. so, I have done to this as follows:

```
2nd Query : which is returned approvalstatus between user1 and other
--------------------------------------------------------------------
START me=node:node_auto_index(UserID = '1')
MATCH me-[myR:friends]-(x)
RETURN x.UserID, myR.ApprovalStatus
ORDER BY x.UserID
```

and finally, I need mutual friend count between user 1 and others as per following query.

```
3rd Query : which is returned mutual count between user1 and other
------------------------------------------------------------------
START me=node:node_auto_index(UserID = '1'), other=node(*)
MATCH pMutualFriends=me-[r:friends]-mf-[r1:friends]-other
WHERE r.ApprovalStatus = 1
AND r1.ApprovalStatus = 1
AND other.FirstName =~ "(?i)dh.*" AND other.UserID <> 1 
RETURN other.UserID, COUNT(pMutualFriends) AS mutualCount
ORDER BY other.UserID
```

Now I want to join all of this query like we do in RDBMS. means result set 1st should return all records, join with 2nd & 3rd result set.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2):

When you query a graph db, you should start with the piece of specific data that you know and work outward on the graph from there. Using `START n=node(*) ...` is very expensive: You are returning the entire list across the entire graph of users. That is not what you want, though, as you only want those that are connected to the user with UserID=1.

```
START me=node:node_auto_index(UserID = '1')
MATCH me-[r:FRIENDS]-friend-[r1:FRIENDS]-other
WHERE other.FirstName =~ "(?i)dh.*" AND other.UserID <> 1
    AND r.ApprovalStatus = 1 AND r1.ApprovalStatus = 1
    AND NOT (me-[:FRIENDS]-> other)
RETURN other.UserID, other.FirstName, COUNT(friend) AS MutualCount
```

This finds all friends of friends (`other`) who have a FirstName that starts with `dh` and counts the number of mutual friends they share with `me`.

I also added the clause `AND NOT (me-[:FRIENDS]-> other)` to remove the case of `other` also being a friend of `me`.

Comment: Thanks @Edward, your query look very useful to me. but one things is missing. I need all node which have firstname started with 'dh'. here in your query returns only those nodes which is connected to user 1. and I want "ApprovalStatus" property from relationship too. can you help me to get desired result?

Comment: Hi @edward, can we join above 3 result set with userid? like RDBMS left join. so, all nodes comes from result 1 with 'ApprovalStatus' from result 2 and 'MutualCount' from result 3. Do you get what I mean to say? awaiting you reply. thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question you are asking of the data. Is it "Find all users who have a name that starts with 'dh' and return the mutual friend count with every person with whom they share a friend."?

Comment: yes @edward, Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947903/search-list-with-mutual-count-2nd-try